# How to invite Facebook friends from iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The current solution I found involves a complex set of process, I have not figured out 100% yet. Thus, I wanted to know an expert opinion on this.

This is what I have so far:

1. Access Graph API endpoint `/friends` which will give the list of friends who are also using the app
2. Invite them (I have no idea how)

For an invite, I have found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/archive/docs/app-invites/ios/), but that's already deprecated. Which uses `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`.

I also found [this](https://medium.com/@VanhishikhaB/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready-6cba5ee42741) but it seems like she is just promoting their own product. If they can do it then there must be a way for me to achieve this as well. Still, I can't find it in Facebook docs.

The sad thing is, why would Facebook make this simple stuff very hard to do?